# eclipse & cmake cdt4: lost in translation

Tags: eclipse, build-process, cmake

I have an out-of-source build setup with cmake and I am trying to generate an Eclipse project. I have one source folder and a seperate build folder for eclipse, the two folders are siblings.

When I generate an Eclipse project the source folder does not end up as part of the eclipse project. Is there any way to annotate the directory so it ends up in the project as a source folder

Since the compile phase works fine, I don't see a need for pasting the cmake files here, I bet this sort of thing is a common issue and therefore there must be a straight-forward way to sidestep it.

p.s., I would also like to know if it is possible to get rid of all the cmake/make related gunk that shows up in the Eclipse project explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did for this situation is add the source directory as a Makefile-based project and manually set and add the build directory into Eclipse.

For hiding the CMake/Make files I used a filter in the project explorer.

Comment: This is the best answer so far I guess -- I would have liked not to take this approach. However, since then I have converted into into a bash-based programmer :D